# Should nested enums be declared as static?

Tags: java, enums, static, nested, conventions

I know that there is no difference in functionality if a nested enum is declared as static or not. However, it makes a difference if a nested class is declared as static or not. In comparison to the scheme of nested classes, nested enums would be always static.

The question is: Is there a kind of java code convention which says that the static keyword should be used when declaring nested enums? How is it handled mainly?

The main reason why I ask this question is that I didn't find any discussion about this topic so far and it might help someone who is also searching for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much just shooters' preference, but I wouldn't. It's redundant since it's an enum, and might make people think it's okay to use the static enum by itself.

So I guess the question is how tightly coupled is the intent of the two enums? Are you using them just as a set of static constants like C# enums or utilizing full functionality? If they have functionality, and it the functionality of the enclosing enum relies upon the nested enum...**definitely** don't static it.